# How do I get my individual modules to work together?

Tags: excel, vba, email, lotus-notes

[image: I have a database which looks very much like this but is definitely not this (for security reasons), which holds customer emails and their unique identifiers in column A and Column B respectively.]

We manually enter information in both Column A and Column B, the worksheet is there to compare the subject lines with.

We get emails that come into our inbox with specific subjects, those subjects match the data in Column B. Those emails further have attachments designated for the email address in Column A. Normally what we do is we check the subject of the email, find the row which contains the same information on the subject as is in column B and then forward that email to the email in Column A for that same row.

```
Dim v As Object
Dim vn As Object
Dim e As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim rtitem As Variant
Dim nit As Object

View = "$All"

Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set NMailDb = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")
If Not NMailDb.IsOpen Then
        NMailDb.OPENMAIL
    End If
    
Set v = NMailDb.GetView(View)
Set vn = v.CreateViewNav()


Set e = vn.GetFirstDocument()


Do While Not (e Is Nothing)

     Set doc = e.Document
     Lines = doc.GetItemValue("subject")
     Range("C1").Resize(UBound(Lines) + 1, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Lines)
     Set e = vn.GetNextDocument(e)

Loop
End Sub
```

This code looks into my Lotus Notes inbox, (I need to have the inbox open for it to work but that's okay) it takes the subject line of each individual email in my inbox and inputs it into C1. Then it does this again with the next email and over-writes C1, this loops until it goes through all the emails over-writing C1 every time.

```
Public Sub SubstringCheck()
Dim i As Long, icount As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim MainString As String
Dim SubString As Variant

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A30000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow

MainString = Range("C1")
SubString = Range("B" & i)


If InStr(1, LCase(MainString), LCase(SubString), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
Forward_Email MainString, Range("A" & i)

icount = icount + 1
ElseIf InStr(LCase(MainString), LCase(SubString)) = 0 Then

End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This code takes whatever is in C1 and compares it with each entry in column B. When it finds a match between C1 and any of the values in column B it then runs the Forward_Email function which goes back to Lotus Notes with the subject line in C1, finds that email by the subject line and forwards it using the email address form that matched row.

My question is, id like to take my code (Substring_Check) and run it within the code that populates C1 with a subject line. Id like to have it run before the next loop over writes C1, this way the Substring_Check can check the information in C1 with the information in Column B, if there are matches it will forward the email if not the loop can then overwrite the information in C1 and repeat. What would be the best way to get this merger to happen?

Comment: where do I start... your code has so much issues and I have NO idea what you want to achieve... Where does Column B in your table come from? Are you aware that you overwrite C1 again and again for every mail? As it is this is totally unclear and I voted to close.... sorry.

Comment: You're right let me try and improve on it @TorstenLink

Comment: The reason that you need to have your Inbox open is because you are using Notes.NoteSession instead of Lotus.NotesSession.

Comment: As far as the answer to your final question goes, I think you just have to call Substring_Check() after you do the Range("C1") assignment but before you do the set e assignment. That's if I understand your question correctly, but that just seems too simple to be what you're really asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written by Richard in his comment the answer seems to be to trivial, but I'll nevertheless try:

You don't need to write C1 at all in your code. Within your loop just add the call for the substring- finding- function with a parameter:

```
Dim subject as String
Do While Not (e Is Nothing)

     Set doc = e.Document
     subject = doc.GetItemValue("subject")(0)
     SubstringCheck subject
     Set e = vn.GetNextDocument(e)

Loop
```

Subject usually only contains one value, we do not need an array for string comparison, we just use the first value and give it to the function as parameter.

```
Public Sub SubstringCheck( MainString as String )
    Dim i As Long, icount As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim SubString As Variant
    
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A30000").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        
        SubString = Range("B" & i)
        
        If InStr(1, LCase(MainString), LCase(SubString), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            Forward_Email MainString, Range("A" & i)
            icount = icount + 1
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(MainString), LCase(SubString)) = 0 Then
        
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is still far from optimal but answers your question...